# steps for share on LinkedIn using API

Tags: java, linkedin-api

I am having difficulty getting a share on LinkedIn. I am trying to post a LinkedIn share update via its Share on LinkedIn API. Does anyone can tell me how to post on linked share update and give me steps to manage it.

Comment: did you try anything ...?

Comment: are you coding an android application or just a web app? If you're not working on an Android application, please change your tag from java to javascript and refer to the answer below. Otherwise, please add more details to your question (specify that you are indeed working on an android app)

Answer (score 0):

First you have to sign into LinkedIn Developers and create an app to get the API code specific to your application: [Login Here](https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login?session_redirect=https://developer.linkedin.com)

Then, the quickest way for you to learn is to look at some examples. Here is a working version of what you are trying to code: http://datopstech.com/linkedin-share-tool/

**The only thing you NEED to change to get this code running for yourself is the API_Key found in the HTML snippet.**

The source for this can be found [here](https://github.com/kaburkett/LinkedIn-Advanced-Share) or, I copied and pasted relevant pieces below for reference:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#submit_button").click(function organizeinput(){
 if (IN.User.isAuthorized() == true){
var values = new Array();
//comment, title, description, image-content, image-url
// Get the parameters as an array
values = $(":input").serializeArray();
// Find and replace `content` if there
var countinput=0;
for (index = 0; index < values.length; ++index) 
 {
     if (values[index].name == "comment" && values[index].value != "") 
     {
         var comment;
         comment = values[index].value;
         countinput=countinput+1;
     }
     if (values[index].name == "title" && values[index].value != "") 
     {
         var title;
         title = values[index].value;
         countinput=countinput+1;
     }
     if (values[index].name == "description" && values[index].value != "") 
     {
        var description;
        description = values[index].value;
        countinput=countinput+1;
     }
     if (values[index].name == "image-content" && values[index].value != "") 
     {
         var imagecontent;
         imagecontent = values[index].value;
         countinput=countinput+1;
     }
     if (values[index].name == "image-url" && values[index].value != "") 
     {
         var imageurl;
         imageurl = values[index].value;
         countinput=countinput+1;
     }
 } 

if (countinput == 5){
var postcontent = new Array();
postcontent = {"comment": comment, "content": {"title": title,"description": description,"submitted-url": imagecontent,"submitted-image-url": imageurl},"visibility": {"code": "anyone"} };
postcontent = JSON.stringify(postcontent);

shareContent(postcontent);
}
else alert("All the fields are required.");
}
else alert("You have to login to linkedin before you can post content.");
});


function onLinkedInLoad() {
   IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", organizeinput);
 }

  // Handle the successful return from the API call
  function onSuccess(data) {
    console.log(data);
    alert("Post Successful!");
  }

  // Handle an error response from the API call
  function onError(error) {
    console.log(error);
    alert("Oh no, something went wrong. Check the console for an error log.");
  }

  // Use the API call wrapper to share content on LinkedIn
  function shareContent(pcontent) {

    IN.API.Raw("/people/~/shares?format=json")
  .method("POST")
  .body(pcontent)
  .result(onSuccess)
  .error(onError);
}


//function executepost (pcontent)
//{
 //$.post("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares?format=json", postcontent, function() {return null;});
 // Setup an event listener to make an API call once auth is complete
 
 
//}

});

/*
$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares?format=json",
    type: 'post',
    data: postcontent,
    headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'x-li-format': 'json'
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        console.info(data);
    }
});*/

// Convert to URL-encoded string
//values = jQuery.param(values);
/*
if (crflag ==1)
{
 $.post("index.php", values, function(response) {processdata(response); return response;});
}
else
{
 alert("Sorry, looks like we are missing some input");
}
//$.post("db_insert.php", $(":input").serializeArray(), function(tabledata){$("#result").html(tabledata);});
*/
Status API Training Shop Blog About Pricing
© 2016 GitHub, Inc. Terms Privacy Security Contact Help
```

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Linkedin Share Link With Image, Choose Picture for Hyperlink Thumbnail, JSON Post Developer, Web Tool, Without Meta Property og: tag Online</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- add jQuery -->
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <!-- add bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!-- user typed js for form -->
  <script src="postscript.js"></script>
  
   <!-- initialize LinkedIn JS SDK -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
  api_key: //YOUR API KEY HERE
  authorize: true
  //onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="wrap"> 
<h1 align="center">Create An Advanced LinkedIn Post</h1>
<p align="center">Configure a share post for Linkedin. First, authorize through LinkedIn by logging in.</br> Then, fill out all of the fields below and click submit to share the content.</br></br><script type="in/Login"></script></p> <br><br>

<div class="col-md-4"><!--quick spacer :)--></div>
 <div class="col-md-5">
  <form name="post_content" action="" method="post">
   <label for="comment">Comment: </label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="comment" placeholder="Comment" required></input><br>
   <label for="title">Title: </label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" placeholder="Title" required></input><br>
   <label for="description">Description: </label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" placeholder="Description" required></input><br>
   <label for="image-content">Link to Content: </label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="image-content" placeholder="http://example.com/content" required></input><br>
   <label for="image-location">Image Location: </label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="image-url" placeholder="http://example.com/images/example.jpg" required></input><br><br>
   <input type="button" id="submit_button" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default"></input>
   
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="VINoutput"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: np. anyway I think javascript is better in this case :-) just checking because of the tags

Comment: posted additional comment on OP's question asking to specify platform and language.

Comment: @KyleBurkett is there a way to put media files like photo or video with a post

Answer (score 0):

Just use a URL like this...

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}
```

Source: **[Microsoft LinkedIn Share URL Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin)**.

For example, this works for me:

> https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=http://www.wikipedia.org/

Demonstration:

[image]